# How can I indent paragraphs within an itemize environment?

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, paragraphs, itemize

I'm sorry to ask such a simple question, but I've been searching around without finding a simple way to make each new paragraph indent when I'm in the `\itemize` environment.

Number 6 on this document is an example of a problem on which I'd like to have paragraphs indented: https://www.writelatex.com/read/dgjdgsptgwhr

Comment: Use `enumitem` with a positive value for `listparindent`. If you want help, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) here. Otherwise, your question is only of use for so long as the problematic code remains at the link you posted. (So no going and sneakily correcting it!) A question should be written to benefit other users and therefore needs to be self-contained and self-explanatory. Moreover, that code is very far from minimal!

Comment: By the way, you want an `enumerate` environment, I think. You are saying e.g. `\item[2.]` which you should (almost) never do. Use an `enumerate` environment so that your items are automatically numbered. This is a lot more flexible and a lot easier to keep consistent. (If you need to add an item at the start of the list, you would need to renumber the entire list by hand.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just to supplement @cfr, I usually use this general configuration

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{  
  listparindent=\parindent,
  parsep=0pt,
}
```

To have paragraphs indented as in the normal doc, and to remove space between paragraphs in lists.

Answer (score 16):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., listparindent=1.5em]
    \item \kant[1-2]
    \item \kant[3-4]
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: paragraphs enumerated]

If you want the first paragraph of an item indented also, you need something like this but will need to play around, probably, to polish it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., listparindent=1.5em, labelsep=2em, itemindent=1.5em]
    \item \kant[1-2]
    \item \kant[3-4]
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: indented first paragraphs enumerated]

Comment: This answer is IMHO the best because of the local use of list modifiers - I was hoping to find an answer that did not include setting the list settings globally.