# Indent doesn't work inside enumerate enviroment

Tags: indentation

I don't know why the 2nd line here is not indented. Have I loaded a package that overrides indentation? It seems not to work inside an enumerate enviroment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber, isbn=false, doi=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}

\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}

\title{Homework 2 - MATH 4001}
\author{Clyde Kertzer}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{5pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{5pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}

\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}
\item[2.] Show that the sequence of functions
$$ f_n(x)=\frac{n x}{1+n x} $$ 
does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Paragraph 2 (Why no indent)?
```

Comment: When I run your code, both paragraphs are indented. Since they are both indented the same amount, and there are no lines long enough to wrap, it's difficult to tell, but if I add more to the paragraphs so that the line wraps, the wrapped line isn't indented as far as the first line. Your screenshot is cropped so it's impossible to tell if you're getting a different result or not.

Comment: as your image shows, both lines are indented by the same amount (20pt)

Comment: You changed your question and now my previous comment doesn't make sense. Anyway, it's normal not to have indentation there. If you want indentation, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214030/how-can-i-indent-paragraphs-within-an-itemize-environment). Unrelated, but you shouldn't use `$$` for display math in LaTeX. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the standard behavior in LaTeX. Whenever a `list` is opened, `\listparindent` is set to zero. A similar behavior have `minipage` and `\parbox`.

If you want to have a different parindent in lists, you have to specify it and the simplest way is to use `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{listparindent=\parindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Show that the sequence of functions
\[
f_n(x)=\frac{n x}{1+n x}
\]
does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Paragraph 2 (Why no indent)?

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following trick hides `\parindent` primitive register, so no macros have write access to this register. They can only read the value, which is copied to the faked `\parindentA` register.

```
\parindent=20pt  % setting desired value
\newdimen\parindentA  \parindentA=\parindent % value is copied  
\let\parindent=\parindentA  % the primitive \parindent is unaccessible after this
\expandafter \let \csname tex_parindent:D\endcsname=\parindentA
```